# How do you use QAbstractOpenGLFunctions in c++?

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

I’m new to OpenGL so this might be a stupid question. It seems like I'm missing something obvious. I can’t see how the new [OpenGL classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qabstractopenglfunctions.html) are supposed to be useful.

[There are classes for each version and profile of OpenGL](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/#more-3420). These classes have explicit methods for all the OpenGL calls supported by each version. Here's a partial list:

- QOpenGLFunctions_1_0
- QOpenGLFunctions_1_1
- QOpenGLFunctions_1_2
- QOpenGLFunctions_1_3
- QOpenGLFunctions_1_4

I assume it would be something like the following:

- query the video card and ask which version(s) of OpenGL it supports.
- instantiate a copy of the class for the highest version supported using QOpenGLContext::versionFunctions()

So how do I write code using this class? I can't predict which object I will get at run time without knowing explicitly what hardware it will run on. The base class contains no methods since they're different for every derived class. I could write a giant switch but that seems a step backward from using QOpenGLFunctions or just getting the function addresses manually.

Comment: But you *can* predict the subset of OpenGL that you're going to use, and ask for a matching version. If the context has a superset of the functions you need, everything will be just fine. Otherwise, those objects will fail to initialize. At the same time: 1) you don't need to resolve each and every OpenGL proc address, and 2) if by any chance you attempt to use a function which is outside the version you chose (f.i. because it has been introduced later, or because it's in the compatibility profile and you're using core) you get a nice compile-time error, instead of a mysterious runtime one.

Comment: I assume you mean can predict the version and profile you _want_ to use. There's no guarantee it will be on the user's machine. So either you pick a version and if they don't have it you tell the user they're out of luck. Or you could write code for every version and put tests everywhere to select the correct code. Which explains why games don't just run on all hardware.

Comment: That's correct. You can put some absolute minimum requirement (f.i.: OpenGL >= 2.1, and FBOs.), then dynamically check if the user actually has some more features (by checking extensions, or the version of the context you got) -- and if so, use them. In this case, those objects in Qt will prevent you to accidentally use non-OpenGL 2.1 calls (because the QOpenGLFunctions_2_1 object will lack the methods).

Comment: Thanks, that was another of my questions. Can you use OpenGL version 2 calls, and if they're present version 3 calls, within the same scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of why these classes are useful is that the previous QOpenGLFunctions class only exposed OpenGL/ES 2.0 functionality. Now they've exposed the full functionality from many versions of OpenGL allowing you to take advantage of the features offered only in those versions.

Of course most developers don't choose a GL version at runtime for most applications. They target a particular version and for that the Qt classes will work very nicely.

If what you're searching for is a way to call the "common" methods between the various QOpenGLFunctions_* classes without knowing which version of OpenGL you're using (while still giving yourself the opportunity to take advantage of specific features of "higher" versions), why not use templating?

For example:

```
template <class T>
class SomeOpenGLRendering {
public:
    SomeOpenGLRendering(T *openglFunctions) : openglFunctions(openglFunctions) {
        openglFunctions->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    }

    void renderSomething() {
        openglFunctions->glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

private:
    T *openglFunctions;
};
```

And then based on whatever criteria you'd like (hardware detection as you said, for example), create the proper version as needed:

```
SomeOpenGLRendering<QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Core> r(new QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Core());
r.renderSomething();
```

Comment: You say "most developers don't choose a GL version at runtime for most applications". How can you choose a specific version with no guarantee that the hardware will have that version?

Comment: For better or worse, you simply need to decide on your minimum requirement and then it's the user's problem to have support if they want to run your app. Here's a good discussion on the subject: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/179176-What-OpenGL-version-do-I-target-Should-I-use-extension-loading-libraries

Comment: NOTE: if SomeOpenGLRendering happens to extend QObject you are screwed as QObject can't be a template.